# premium gift reports not showing size ordered

Tags: reports

we set up a premium gift ( a t-shirt) for a donation.   now i can't find a report that tells me what size of t shirt they wanted.  I have downloaded contribution reports but it's not there.  need to know the size so i can mail them out

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of extensions that give more detailed reporting on line items

- [Line Item Report](https://civicrm.org/blog/jproffitt/announcing-the-line-item-report-extension)
- [Extended Report](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport)

One of these may be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'Contribution and Membership Details' report from the 'Membership Reports' section.

That lets you show the premium, premium option and fulfilment date although it does not allow you to filter on those values.

Comment: still did not show what size of Tshirt they had asked for.   any other suggestions?